# What we should use instead of a "manager" class in a good OOP design?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I'm having trouble designing my game engine. For example:

When I think in **Resources**, I think in a **ResourceManager** class to manage resources on my engine.

This class **gets several responsibilities**:

- Load resources.
- Map resources by an identifier.
- Ensure that resources are loaded only once.
- Free unused resources (using smartpointers).

This works for me, but I have read on every OOP design tutorial that managers are **ambiguous** classes with **high coupling** and **low cohesion**. I understand this, and I agree, but I searched almost the whole Internet to find a clear example of a real alternative to Managers but I didn't found it.

Some people explain, for example that a ResourceManager should be divided into smaller classes: A **ResourceFactory**, a **ResourceCollection**, a **ResourceCache**, a **ResourceFacade**...

I know all this design patterns (Factory, Collection, Facade, etc.) But I don't actually understand how this can be joined to create a (easy to manage) resource management system.

**My question is:** Is there some tutorial or document with a clear example? Can someone explain an example of this system? I'll thank you if you can write a small example in C++ or another similar language.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Maybe:

- Load resources -> `ResourceLoader`
- Map resources by an identifier -> `ResourceMapper`
- Ensure that resources are loaded only once -> `CachedResourceLoader` / this one uses the `ResourceLoader` when it doesn't already have it loaded
- Free unused resources (using smartpointers) -> ? / not sure about this one, but load+unload seems like highly cohesive concepts

---

**re extra info in the comment about "Free unused resources":**

First, let's clear that we only have 2 of the above involved: ResourceMapper and CachedResourceLoader. As the ResourceLoader instance is used from the CachedResource, it's not exposed to the rest of the code.

Note that the following depends on the domain knowledge, so I'll keep it open / you'll know which of these make sense / applies to the pieces you have. I'd say there are 3 options here:

- ResourceMapper uses CachedResourceLoader, and you only expose the earlier to the rest of the code.

  - In this approach it there is a single entry point through ResourceMapper, so it makes sense it controls FreeUnused().
  - Once it determines it can free a resource, it'll remove it from the map. If needed it'd call an Unload for specific items to the CachedResourceLoader
- Both CachedResourceLoader and ResourceMapper are used by the caller.

  - If you only need to FreeUnused from the ResourceMapper, then just add it there.
  - If it needs to be freed from both, one of:
  - .FreeUnused in the ResourceMapper receives a cachedResourceLoader. After determining/removing the items from the map, it passes the list of resources to free to the cachedResourceLoader instance
  - .FreeUnused in the ResourceMapper returns the list of resources freed from the map. The caller calls .Unload on the cachedResourceLoader passing the list of resources to Unload. Maybe you have a nice place in the caller these 2 calls would fit well.
- You do use a ResourceManager, but instead of having all the implementations in there, it uses the ResourceMapper and CachedResourceLoader. It'd be very thin, just doing calls to the others, in particular the .FreeUnused and .Unload calls in the last sub bullet above.

**A final note:** I think it's definitely worth it to separate the responsibilities and feel strong about doing so. That said, it's the SOLID principles I follow the most, I don't memorize pattern names and don't pay that much attention to rules like Manager classes are bad.

Comment: **About "Free unused resources":** To store resources in memory, I use smartpointers of type "reference counted". So that by reading the reference count on each resource in the ResourceMap I can see what resources are no longer used in my application. If this count is 1, means that the only reference on that resource is in the ResourceMap. So I can free it safely. In my old resource manager, I had a method FreeUnused() to perform this task. But now that the manager is out, where should I put this method? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Dani: Delete it. And then use a *real* reference-counted smart pointer (such as the one in Boost). A sane smart pointer implementation *automatically* deletes the object when its reference count reaches zero (and to answer your next question, your ResourceMap can then hold weak pointers, to avoid it keeping objects alive by preventing the the ref counter from reaching zero)

Comment: @jalf: Great!! I haven't used much weak pointers, but if I understand it, I don't need no FreeUnused method. That's right? When all references on an object are deleted, the resource is freed. And if a process needs the resource again it ask the ResourceMap who will get a bad weak_ptr and reload again with CachedResourceLoader... Is this OK?

Comment: @Dani: yep, sounds about right. In general, the magic word is RAII: every resource should have its lifetime mapped to that of a wrapper class. Smart pointers are one example of such wrapper objects (a ref-counted one deletes the resource it owns when the ref counter reaches zero, but many other types exist). In general, this allows you to write C++ code where resources just manage themselves, and are automatically deleted when they're no longer needed. Either when they go out of scope, or when their reference counter reaches zero.

Comment: **About "Load resources":** If I have a class "Resource", is it a bad idea to let resources load themselves by calling "Resource->Load(resource_id)" ? Is it necessary to get ResourceLoader appart? (may be this must be post as a new question...)

Comment: "Is it necessary" no, but personally I avoid doing it. The main issue I've had (in business apps) is that you could consider the same about many different things i.e. load/save metadata to a db, log, authorize access to, more. It then increases the pain on deciding where to fit a new piece in the system. I also find it easier to unit test having it separated. That said, don't take my word for it, I'd just pick one and move further and after having more scenarios in place, I'd re-evaluate and refactor if neccesary.

Comment: One big difference in how I develop now and how I did in the past, is that I spend a lot less time in up front design (but I constantly re-evaluate the pieces I happen to be working on); go for simple solutions trying to take DRY+SOLID into account while doing it

Comment: but... If I have ResourceLoaders separated from Resources, and if I'm loading a set of files which resource type ids are coming from a stream, I'll need a ResourceLoaderFactory (as well as a ResourceFactory for general purpose)... or is there a better way?

Answer (score 17):

You almost said it already:

> This class **gets several responsibilities**

(original emphasis).

This violates the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Additionally, the word *Manager* suggest an object that manages other objects, which is at odds with the object-oriented principle that objects should encapsulate both **data and behavior**. This quickly leads to the [Feature Envy](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FeatureEnvySmell) code smell.

Dividing the manager into many smaller classes is the correct thing to do. To keep them manageable, you can implement a [Facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) over them.

Comment: "the object-oriented principle that objects should encapsulate both data and behavior." Great quote! I think a lot of developers, especially those in the land o' Flex, get so wrapped around the axle with regard to micro-architectures for "future supportability," that many tend to argue for "writing it this way for new developers who are hired." They have model mediators, presentation models, and 50 more files and package layers than are truly necessary. Making a Form 'aware' of it's own data, even when it makes absolute sense, is a sin and grounds for religious debate!  (my 2p. Good answer!)

Comment: (and while my example violates the S of SOLID, the bottom line, to me, is to make your code easy to read, easy to support, and easy to understand.... sorry.... done blabbing now.  I'm dehydrated.)

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! I have followed the link "Feature Envy". I didn't know that term, and it is very interesting thing to keep in mind. Now I started to read the book that appears in this web (named: "Refactoring: Improving the design of existing code"). I'm sure that this will help me a lot. Thanks again!

Comment: I don't think a Manager is anything wrong if the Manager class conceptually maps to something like in real life. Like a BookManager is a way to represent a library, CarManager represents a garage/parking-lot, etc.

Comment: I also think some people push OO so hard with all these 'principles' and 'idioms' that it's virtually impossible to write any code that meets them all. Few of these are Holy Writ after all - they are just different peoples' ideas on how to approach OO, not laws.

Comment: @John: No, a Library is a way to represent a library. A "Bookmanager" is... something that manages books. I don't even know what that means. A garage doesn't "manage cars" it just stores cars while they're not in use, sometimes charging money for it. That is exactly the problem with manager classes. *It's not clear what they mean*. When I encounter a "CarManager" class, should I assume that it just your name for a garage? Or perhaps it's some big controller class that periodically updates the position of every car which is currently driving? Perhaps it is a centralized registry of all cars.

Comment: You don't know what it means? Look at the public API.

Comment: And to keep it manageable divide the Facade into many smaller facades each with single responsibility and wrap a Facade over that facades... )  Sorry, I can't be any more constructive, since the answer is just a collection of buzzwords

Comment: @jalf: Many types of resources require that something be done to release them when they are no longer needed (files need to be closed, memory blocks released, etc.)  If one can predict which object will be the last one to use a resource, then it's easy to have that object tell the resource when it's done with it.  In some contexts, however, that doesn't work so well; some kind of object is needed to wrap resource creation and release.  If it's not a "manager", what is it?

Comment: @supercat: In C++, it is called a "smart pointer". :) In other languages, well, it varies. Most languages these days are garbage-collected, so the object will be destroyed at some point when it is no longer used. You don't need a special class for that.

Comment: @jalf: In some cases a "smart pointer" may not be enough.  For example, a USB device driver may only allow one "driver instance" to be open for a particular device, even if the protocol used by the device could support multiple applications simultaneously.  In that case, if one object wants to get a connection to device with location ID 1391, and another object already has a connection to that device, some sort of "manager object" would have to recognize that the connection is already open, and return a wrapper to that open connection.

Comment: @supercat A `ConnectionRegistry` perhaps? I don't disagree with you that such tasks sometimes exist and need to be carried out by *some* part of the code. But when it does, give it a descriptive name. "Manager" can mean anything or nothing at all. You don't know *what* it manages, or *how* it manages, or just as importantly, which aspects of "managing" it does *not* do. The first step in building a manager class should always be to ask yourself "so how does it *manage*", and when you have the answer to that, you can rename it. ;)

Comment: @jalf: The behavior goes a bit beyond a `ConnectionRegistry`, since I would not expect a "registry" to be responsible for requesting the creation of new objects (and probably not the cleanup of old ones).  The "manager" may do a number of things, but it has *one responsibility*: maintaining the invariant that the set of things that exist and are not eligible to be disposed or recycled matches the set of things that clients actually need.

Comment: @supercat but why are you mixing those things? You said you wanted something to ensure that connections would be reused: if I want to talk to a USB device, I ask this registry for a connection. If it has one already, it reuses that, otherwise it creates one. (or it says "I don't have one", and you create it and place it in the registry, if you prefer). It doesn't need to do cleanup of old ones. They can do that themselves. Again, smart pointers, my friend. ;)

Comment: You insist on mixing multiple concerns, and use that as an argument for naming the class a "manager". Make it do one thing instead, and name it after that one thing. Is it a registry? Is it a factory? Name it that way! You've illustrated very aptly what the problem is with "manager" classes. They do *everything*. You want them to create objects, and destroy objects, and *know when* to create and destroy objects, and store references to all existing objects, and tell the caller which object instance to (re)use. *That should not be one class*

Comment: @jalf: When I hear the term "registry", I think of something that will say whether something exists has been added to it, but not wrap object creation or cleanup.  For the registry to maintain its invariants, it must wrap the creation and cleanup of the objects it's managing.  If someone wanting a new `Foo` asks whether one exists, and then creates one if the registry says it doesn't, even if it then adds its new `Foo` to the registry, there will at minimum be a time during which a `Foo` exists that the registry doesn't know about, as well as possibilities of race conditions.

Comment: As for cleaning up resources, if one simply used smart pointers, how would items get removed from the registry when they were no longer needed elsewhere?  Do they offer some means of holding a "weak reference" and ensuring that it will get invalidated just before the reference count hits zero?  I'm only familiar with GC-based oop systems, and the question seemed GC agnostic.  Certainly in a non-GC system, one wouldn't use smart pointers since such things don't exist (the manager class would exist in some measure to mimic their functionality).

Comment: I think this is the best answer. Let the Manager class **manage** like you want it to, and turn it into a facade if you need to do so in order to let it manage everything. Use subclasses as properties of the facade Manager class. Overlapping responsibilities means you need an abstraction class to manage it.

Answer (score 14):

You don't need to be dogmatic about design patterns or a particular architecture. Just *do whatever makes sense and document it well*.

In other words, decomposing a class into smaller classes because the larger class has multiple responsabilities is a good principle, but not a *law*. You don't want to follow it at any cost. Look at the pros and cons of applying it. Sometimes, decomposing a class into smaller classes gives you more control over responsaibilities, but at the expense of a great deal of communication among those classes. In your example, you might as well implement different classes for resource loading, caching, mapping, saving, etc. But if each class needs to talk to the others in order to perform its work, then the decomposition is not worth doing, because it entails high coupling, which is bad; keep it all in a single class.

Sometimes I think that design patterns have brought about as much damage as clarity to the software development world! :-)

Comment: I agree whole-heartedly with you on all of your 2nd and 3rd paragraph points... in a word or few: "nailed it!"  However, the 'document it well' is a sore-spot in our little shop.  There are classes that have more comments than lines of code by five-fold.  I contend (and contend and contend) that if your classes are well-named (i.e. FileDownloader) and name your methods clearly (i.e. downloadFileAsynchronously), you shouldn't have to document "well", you should only have to document enough to make future support a manageable task.  I even think this is true for open source projects...

Comment: @jeremy.mooer: +1 "Document well" doesn't mean "document too much" or "document the hell out of it". It means just what it says: document it *well*. Carefully chosen names for classes and methods plus a few extra comment lines for specially difficult logic code sections is all you need to achieve what I mean by "document it well". I fully agree with you!

Comment: @CesarGon - I guess when I hear "document it well" I hear the stirring echoes of friendly arguments past in which I'm accused of the opposite: not documenting well enough.  Could be a personal problem.... :-)

Comment: I agree with your last paragraph, but you picked a really bad example for it. If all of your classes need to talk to all the others in order to perform their work, then your entire architecture is broken. Then you have that much more reason to decompose the classes, rather than just saying "oh well, can't be done, I'll just go on with my big huge God Class"

Comment: @jeremy.mooer: Happens to me too :-)

Comment: @jalf: Let's stick to the example, please, and let's not get carried away with God Classes or whole architectures. :-) I didn't say that *all* your classes need to talk to each other, only that the classes that are candidate for decomposition from a single class need to talk to each other. In making a decomposition decision, that happens often, and that is a frequent sign that you should stop decomposing; we often make that decision without even realising, thanks to our accumulated experiences.

Answer (score 10):

I don't think something is necessarily wrong with your solution.
IMHO if you think about stuff you've said from **Aspect Oriented Programming**'s point of view,
it's just an aspect on your resources that will be handled by a class.

Although if you think in large, your code base may evolved in hundreds of lines, so it would be better to break down your Infrastructure functions(**Domain Driven Design** Patterns).

I think your class is a cohesive one and the `manager` name is not always a bad sign except that it consolidates the control flow of many possibly unrelated classes that collaborate with each other to accomplish a task.

If your requirements about caching and mapping is prone to change maybe it would be better to **Separate your Concerns.**

Rule of thumb when trying to write a well organized code is don't take it too serious at first, watch out code smells as you go forward and refactor or refactor to patterns when necessary.

Answer (score 4):

> I know all this design patterns (Factory, Collection, Facade, etc.) But I don't actually understand how this can be joined to create a (easy to manage) resource management system.

Who says they should be joined together? Then you're back where you started, aren't you? The entire point in breaking up manager classes is that you end up with multiple simpler components. If you need the caching functionality, you talk to the cache. If you need the resource loading functionality you talk to the resource loader.